# Prove that theory is not Henkin one

Tags: logic, formal-languages

The definition as it was given to me: The theory $T$ is Henkin theory, if and only if for every formula $\phi$ in $T$ we have constant $c$ language of $T$ such as $T \vdash \exists x \phi \to \phi(x/c)$.
How I have language $\mathcal L = \{ c \}$, where $c$ is a constant, and I have to prove that theory $T = \{ \emptyset \}$ over language $\mathcal L$ is not a Henkin one. My problem is that I don't know how to even prove this, if there is no formulas in the language to "check Henkin condition". How do I approach this task?

Comment: What about, say, the formula $x = y$?

Comment: Mind if I ask what is your reference for the subject?

Comment: By the way... with your defintion it seems that the empty theory is an Henkin theory.

Answer (score 2):

If the theory $T$ has **no** non-logical axioms (this is my reading of $T=\{ ∅ \}$) then - by soundness - it can prove only *valid* formulae.

Assuming that $T$ is an *Henkin theory*, then for every formula $ϕ$ in the language of $T$ we have a constant $c$ such that $T ⊢ ∃xϕ→ϕ[x/c]$.

Thus, also : $T \vdash ∃x \ \lnot \phi \to \lnot \phi [x/c]$, and then, by contraposition :

> $T \vdash \phi [x/c] \to \forall x \ \phi$

which is clearly *invalid*.